# How to stop PyCharm inserting spaces for fine alignment when reformating code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm indenting my Python code using tabs and PyCharm is very keen on doing fine alignment using spaces, while it doesn't make the code invalid I would like to know how to stop that behavior.

Here for instance, 2 spaces were inserted before each elements except the first one to maintain the alignment with it.

```py
INDEXES_TO_ILLUMINANTS = {0: "Unknown",
                          1: "DayLight",
                          2: "Fluorescent",
                          3: "Tungsten (Incandescent Light)",
                          4: "Flash",
                          9: "Fine Weather"}
```

Comment: You could go all-spaces per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces); most editors will support the tab key inserting spaces

Comment: Cannot really do that we are full tab at work and as a result my own codebase is all tab, tabs and camelCase actually!

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 5, the "Collections: Align when multiline" setting adds those spaces:

[image: "Collections: Align when multiline" setting adds those spaces.]

Answer (score -1):

Per [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/general.html) it seems you can turn off "smart tabs":

> - If this check box is selected, PyCharm inserts tabs for indentation and reformatting, but fine alignment to a necessary column is done only via spaces without replacing them with tabs. This is done in order to preserve visual representation of the source code, when the Tab Size is changed.
> - If this check box is cleared, only tabs are used. This means that a group of spaces that fits the specified tab size is automatically replaced with a tab, which may result in breaking fine alignment.

Comment: Yeah it's what I was expecting too but if I untick "Smart Tabs" I still have the alignement spaces, and if I tick it the whole indentation is turned into spaces.

I will actually check on their side if its not a bug and also mark your answer as valid if it's an issue with the version I'm using.